# RSpec partial match against a nested hash

Tags: rspec

I've got a JSON structure that I'd like to match a single nested element in, while ignoring other data. The JSON looks like this (minimally):

```
{
  "employee": {
    "id": 1,
    "jobs_count": 0
  },
  "messages": [ "something" ]
}
```

Here's what I'm using right now:

```
response_json = JSON.parse(response.body)
expect(response_json).to include("employee")
expect(response_json["employee"]).to include("jobs_count" => 0)
```

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
expect(response_json).to include("employee" => { "jobs_count" => 0 })
```

Unfortunately, `include` requires an exact match for anything but a simple top-level key check (at least with that syntax).

**Is there any way to partially match a nested hash while ignoring the rest of the structure?**

Answer (score 41, accepted):

With rspec 3.6.0, this works for me:

```
expect(subject).to match(a_hash_including(key: value))
```

Comment: This worked for me while the accepted answer didn't!

Comment: Changing the accepted answer to this one, as the older version no longer works.

Answer (score 45):

You are able to use and nest the `hash_including` method for these matchers.

Using your example, you can rewrite your test code to look like:

```
expect(response_json).to include(hash_including({
  employee: hash_including(jobs_count: 0)
}))
```

(or if `response_json` is a single object, replace `include` with `match`)

This will also work when dealing with `.with` constraints, for example:

```
expect(object).to receive(:method).with(hash_including(some: 'value'))
```

Comment: TIL - nesting `hash_including`!

Comment: Did not work for me, but `expect(response_json).to include(employee: hash_including(jobs_count: 0))` did. I guess cannot use the `include` matcher with `hash_including`, only need one.