# How to use expect with nested hashes in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

In my code I have several conditions that look like:

```
if condition1
   a = some_hash["a"]["b"]
elsif condition2
   b = some_hash["c"]["d"]
```

How do I test and mock these nested hash assignments with `expect` or some similar rspec function to ensure the proper assignment is occurring?

Comment: Specs are for testing the return value of a method, not the behavior within a method. You don't have a method defined here so there's nothing to test. A proper [mre] may help illuminate your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following answer, which I believe answers your question: [RSpec partial match against a nested hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325820/rspec-partial-match-against-a-nested-hash)

In a nutshell, you can use the following syntax:

```
expect(object).to receive(:method).with(hash_including(some: 'value'))
```

But comment by @anothermh is valid — you do not have a proper RSpec setup there. You need something like the following:

```
RSpec.describe ClassName do 
  it 'should have nested value' do
     expect(object).to receive(:method).with(hash_including(some: 'value'))
  end
end
```